# minimize p norm of f+c

Tags: calculus, real-analysis

Say we are considering a function $f$ in $L^p[-1,1]$, I've tried some examples and it seems that $\min_c||f-c||_p$ is obtained when $c$ is equal to the average of $f$ in $[-1,1]$.

Is it true? If yes, how to prove it?

Comment: Never mind. I've already found a counter example. $e^x$ in $L^4$ doesn't follow this rule.